# jquery validation addMethod not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I have a div in jsp as follows:

```
 <input type="text" id="year" placeholder=" Year"  class="year"  name= "year" value=""/>
```

I want to calculate the difference between current year and entered year. I have to show the error if the value does not lie within some range. This is my custome jquery validator function.

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod('validAge', function (value, element, params) {
    alert("inside add method");
    var currentYear = (new Date).getFullYear();
    var range = currentYear - $element.val();;
    if(range >10 && range< 70) 
        {
        return  true;
        }
    return false;
}),
```

But it is showing error at element.val
I have defined the rule as

```
 $('#signup_form').validate({ // initialize the plugin

    rules: {
        year: {
            validage: true,
           },
    },
    messages: {
        year: "Invalid year",
   },
   },
  });
```

Comment: `validage != validAge`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In jquery addMethod element (the element to be validated) and value (the current value of the validated element)

```
 jQuery.validator.addMethod("validAge", function (value, element, params) {
        alert("inside add method");
        var currentYear = (new Date).getFullYear();
        var range = currentYear - value;

       return this.optional(element) || (range >10 && range< 70) 

    },'Enter range in between 10 to 70');
```

Remove commas where not needed and also see case sensitiveness.

```
var validator = $('#form').validate({
    rules: {
        year: {
            validAge: true
        }
    },
    messages: {
        year: "Invalid year"
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Method name is not properly spelled, check 'validage' instead of 'validAge'